# gRPC-web service working fine, but not with bloomRPC

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-web

based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/browser?view=aspnetcore-5.0) tutorial, I have successully set up an ASP.NET 5.0 Core grpc-Web server and have successfully accessed it with the client application described in the tutorial. However, I am unable to call the service with [bloomRPC](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc); posting the request

```
{
  "name": "Test"
}
```

I get the following error message.

```
{
  "error": "full url: http://0.0.0.0:5000/greet.Greeter/SayHello, code: 2,
  err: Http response at 400 or 500 level"
}
```

surprisingly, however, I am getting the desired response

```
{
  "message": "Hello Test"
}
```

when using bloomRPC accessing the "non-web" grpc service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

BloomRPC is a tool to perform pure gRPC requests. gRPC-web adds a simple HTTP web layer on top of your gRPC server.

That means you can use any HTTP client to call a gRPC-web service. Ex Postman